# javascript multidimensional Array and associative array

Tags: javascript

i am new of javascript, i have been told by someone, he said "speak strictly, javascript doesn't have  multidimensional Array and associative array ". but in a book, i saw the following

```
var my_cars=Array();
my_cars["cool"]="Mustang";

$a=Array(Array(0,1),2);
```

so the opinion form  he is wrong? am i right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript has arrays of whom their elements can be other arrays.

However, JavaScript has `Object`s with properties, not associative arrays.

[Buy a better book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742).

1. `[]` is much better than `Array()`. Also, why not instantiate an `Array` object explicitly then rely on `Array` returning a new object?
2. The example is setting the property `cool` on the `Array`.
3. Why the `$a` sigil? Why no `new` operator again?

Comment: Yes, JS:TGP is essential reading for anyone who does anything more than dabble with Javascript.  Also, MDC's JS reference is a fantastic resource. See, e.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#section_20

Answer (score 4):

All the explanations of Javascript Multidimensional arrays seem to be very convoluted, after almost an hour of research I came across this simple example:

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray['row1'] = { 'col1':'BLARGH!!!', 'col2':'HONK!!!!' }
myArray['row2'] = { 'col1':'FOO!!!', 'col2':'BAR!!!!' }
myArray['row3'] = { 'col1':'FOUR!!!', 'col2':'GREGS!!!' }

document.write(myArray['row2']['col1'] + " - " + myArray['row3']['col2']);
//will output: FOO!!! - GREGS!!
```

I found it here: http://moblog.bradleyit.com/2009/06/create-multidimensional-associative.html

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, excellent! And I test it more and this is how to do it for a non associative: `var myArray = new Array(); myArray[0] = {0:1}; alert(myArray[0][0]);`

Answer (score 2):

The line: `my_cars["cool"]="Mustang";` is actually not adding a value into the array. It is in fact adding a new property and value to the object `my_cars`. The following code would also work same:

```
var my_cars = new Function();
my_cars["cool"]="Mustang";
alert(my_cars["cool"]);

var c = new Object();
c["cool"]="Corvette";
alert(c["cool"]);
```

To understand how this works, you can check out [my blog post on arrays and maps](https://rahuldotout.wordpress.com/2011/06/17/javascript-a-different-beast-part-8-array-map-and-the-for-in-loop/).

Btw, as @alex says, Buy A New Book.